# Hbase passing value in custom comparator

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to write a Custom comparator for the first time. Wherein I need to pass two values to this comparator. One will be value which needs to be compared and one is criteria upon which I need to write compare logic. Below is the code for the same :

```
public class IdComparator  extends WritableByteArrayComparable {

private String criteria;

static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(IdComparator.class);

public IdComparator(){
    //NoOp
}

public IdComparator(byte[] value,byte[] criteria){
    super(value);
    this.criteria = new String(criteria);
}

public String getCriteria(){
    return this.criteria;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(byte[] value, int offset, int length) {
    String csv_CBC = new String(value, offset, length);
    LOG.info("IdComparator    :: csv :: "+csv);
    byte[] bytesToCompare = this.getValue();
    LOG.info("IdComparator    :: csv :: "+new String(bytesToCompare) + "  criteria :: "+getCriteria());
    //filtering logic goes here
    return result;
}

}
```

Now when I call this comparator filter and pass some values as

```
new SingleColumnFilter(....,
   new IdComparator(Bytes.toBytes("1234"),Bytes.toBytes("1")));
```

In logger I get the value as Test but the second value which is 1 is not getting printed and printing as null. Below is what I got in logs :

```
IdComparator    :: csv :: 56783,44445,56664,97633
IdComparator    :: csv :: 1234  criteria :: null
```

The first value which is 1234 will be passed to super class which WritableByteArrayComparable and other one which is "1" and the same I will be using for comparison logic, setting for this class only. Is there any thing I am missing or I need to add? Any help will be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer versions we need to create protobufs, since in newer versions protobuf is being used for serialization and de-serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I had to implement ***readFields*** and ***write*** methods which comes from writable interface to get it done.